# Thevenin to Norton transformation question

Tags: resistors, thevenin, norton

I know that I can simplify the circuit below by finding a voltage source + resistor combination and transforming that into a Norton equivalent, but in this case, I can apparently combine the two circled resistors into one 6k resistor and create a Norton equivalent where the current sourse is outputting 2mA in parallel with a 6k resistor.

I don't understand why the two circled resistors can be combined though. Even though they have the same current, they're not in series, so they can't be combined, right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try making an I-V plot for the combination of the 12 V source with the 2 and 4 kOhm resistors.

Then make an I-V plot for a 12 V source in series with a 6 kOhm resistor.

If there's no difference between those two plots, then the two circuits are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The 2k resistor, 4k resistor, and the voltage sources are all in series, *all three*. The current goes through all three components, therefore they are in series; we can combine the two resistors, and if we had another voltage source, we could combine the voltage sources. The voltage at the terminals of the components with respect to A or B might change, but the voltage *across* each component doesn't change, nor does the behaviour of the circuit as a whole.

It may not be completely intuitive, but once you get the hang of it, it seems simple:

Consider what happens when we swap the voltage source and one of those resistors: the voltage drop across the three components as a whole is the same, the current through all three components is still the same. To the rest of the circuit, nothing has changed, and therefore it's allowed.

If it still doesn't make sense, you can solve without combining the resistors, and convince yourself that it works.